# what is REST API to unlink the dropbox account from mobile?

Tags: dropbox-api

I want to implement the Dropbox application in J2ME. 
The authorization process of Dropbox includes the consumer key & secret embedded in the source code, to be included in the very initial step /oauth/request_token.
In the next step, the corresponding user id & password will be given in web and allow/reject the accessing of this account.

In this case, the problem comes if we want to access a different dropobox account.

is there any REST API to unlink this app from dropbox account?
Can it be possible to link/unlink with multiple dropbox accounts?
Any idea about this question? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you no longer want to access the linked account, you can just discard the access token you got for that account.  You can then go through the OAuth flow again and you'll get a new access token for the new account.

If your application hasn't been approved for "production" yet, then it can only be used with your own Dropbox account by default.  But you can enable 5 additional users by going to [dropbox.com/developers/apps](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps), clicking on the "Options" for your app, and then clicking "Enable addtional users".

If you want more than that, you'll have to apply for "production" status.